# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependencies, .net-assembly

I know there are several similar topics on SO about this problem (believe me, I spent the last two days reading all of those), but none of them helped in my strange situation. 
So I come here, maybe somebody can enlighten me what could be the problem.

We have a source of a C# (WPF) control, TreeListView. 
It's compiled with VS2015 dev command prompt using csc.exe (part of bigger project, IDE is not used for compilation) with the following parameters:

```
/reference:"System.Xaml.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\PresentationCore.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\WindowsBase.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\WindowsFormsIntegration.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\PresentationFramework.dll" 
/nowarn:1701,1702 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /platform:x86 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /target:library  /out:..\debug\TreeListView.dll  

...here all the .cs source files are listed...

/resource:"..\TreeListView\obj\debug\TreeListView.g.resources"
```

All of our C#/WPF DLL is compiled with the same options in the command line.

It compiles fine, I have the TreeListView.dll. It is not strong named.
It is copied next to the mainApp.exe, and when I run the main app, and trying to use a window with this TreeListView, I got exception

```
*** Exception ***: System.IO.FileLoadException
Message: Could not load file or assembly 'TreeListView, PublicKeyToken=ffedd4b1334b06f5' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Source: mscorlib
```

The main_app compiled also with csc.exe, referencing **exactly** the output of the above compiled TreeListView.dll

Btw, don't know why it displays public key, when it's not strong named

```
sn -T debug\TreeListView.dll

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

debug\TreeListView.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly
```

**Other observation**

In VS2015 IDE, I created a new WPF app, and referenced the above compiled TreeListView.dll - and used the control in the XAML: it immediately shows in the GUI XAML Designer that `Could not load file or assembly 'TreeListView, PublicKeyToken=ffedd4b1334b06f5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`
(note, here the error is `The system cannot find the file specified.`)

[image]

I thougth IDE will give more information, but nothing new here.

**Other info:**
This whole build/run process worked fine with VS2008 (.NET3.5), now after moving to VS2015 (.NET4), updaexperiencing this, and only with this TreeControl.dll

I checked all references of that dll, used framework, with ILSpy, ildasm, ProcessMonitor for file not found, etc but could not find anything useful.

ildasm > manifest of TreeControl.dll - this also looks ok to me

```
// Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern PresentationFramework
{
  .publickeytoken = (31 BF 38 56 AD 36 4E 35 )                         // 1.8V.6N5
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern System.Xaml
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern WindowsBase
{
  .publickeytoken = (31 BF 38 56 AD 36 4E 35 )                         // 1.8V.6N5
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern PresentationCore
{
  .publickeytoken = (31 BF 38 56 AD 36 4E 35 )                         // 1.8V.6N5
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern System
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern System.Core
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
```

Any idea what to check would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Fuslogvw for failed binding at the run-time. At the time when you are running the application set settings to 'Log binding failures to disk'.

Any failed bindings will be logged on the window. You can double click on the logs to get full details about which dll is trying to load TreeListView assembly and what all locations it is trying to look for that dll.

Comment: Thank you very much!
This tool helped me, error was: `WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY TOKEN`
It was already strange to me that the exception contained: "PublicKeyToken=ffedd4b1334b06f5", when the binary was NO strong named, see above.
However, text searching in the binary showed that it contained "PublicKeyToken=ffedd4b1334b06f5".
I found that a binary file which is used during csc.exe compilation (TreeListView.g.resources-this binary is generated by IDE ) contained this key.

Comment: **...continue...**
In IDE, loaded TreeListView project, then unchecked "sign assembly", and rebuilt to re-generate TreeListView.g.resources.
This did not contain any public key, checked with file search.
Then re-compiled the TreeListView.dll with csc.exe (now using the new TreeListView.g.resources), and it works!

So in short, when TreeListView.g.resources was generated, it was with option "sign assembly", but the final TreeListView.dll was not strongnamed, but still partially somehow it was signed, but "invisible" - however caused exception.